# Порядок чтения в Python и разница в порядке декодирования bytes

Tags: python, кодировка

Столкнулся с проблемой, в порядке декодирования символов при чтении.
У меня есть файл в кодировке cp1251, я пытаюсь открыть его.

```
try:
    with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
        bytes_ = f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Файл не валиден')
    sys.exit(-1)
print(bytes_.decode('cp1251'))
```

Содержимое файла file.txt:

```
Название    Ссылка  Теги    Оценка
Мифы современной популярной физики  https://habr.com/ru/post/442444/    физика  5
Жизнь на частицах   https://habr.com/ru/post/442128/    физика  4
Чем светит Crew Dragon Роскосмосу   https://habr.com/ru/post/442484/    космос  5
Отправка сообщений об опечатках в публикациях   https://habr.com/ru/company/tm/blog/442208/ опечатки    4
Google Safe Browsing — пришла беда откуда не ждали  https://habr.com/ru/post/440240/    иб  3
Реинтродукция зубров (маленькая победа зоологов)    https://habr.com/ru/post/442032/    экология    3
Плотность сюжета в рознице  https://habr.com/ru/company/mosigra/blog/442376/    розница 1
```

Файл считывается с лишними переносами строк:

```
Название    Ссылка  Теги    Оценка

Мифы современной популярной физики  https://habr.com/ru/post/442444/    физика  5

Жизнь на частицах   https://habr.com/ru/post/442128/    физика  4

Чем светит Crew Dragon Роскосмосу   https://habr.com/ru/post/442484/    космос  5

Отправка сообщений об опечатках в публикациях   https://habr.com/ru/company/tm/blog/442208/ опечатки    4

Google Safe Browsing — пришла беда откуда не ждали  https://habr.com/ru/post/440240/    иб  3

Реинтродукция зубров (маленькая победа зоологов)    https://habr.com/ru/post/442032/    экология    3

Плотность сюжета в рознице  https://habr.com/ru/company/mosigra/blog/442376/    розница 1
```

В то время как код:

```
try:
    with open(filename, encoding='cp1251') as f:
        text = f.read()
except FileNotFoundError:
    print('Файл не валиден')
    sys.exit(-1)
print(text)
```

Считывает всё так, как нужно. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Загляните в содержимое `bytes_` и посмотрите, какие именно байты стоят на месте переносов строк

Comment: по умолчанию `with open(filename, encoding='cp1251') as f:`  у Вас `mode='r'`
а не `mode='rb'`

Comment: посмотреть содержимое можете так `f = open('file.txt','rb')` и `list(f)`

Comment: Скорее всего дело не в декодировании, а в символах конца строки. Под windows это два символа - `b'\n\r'`. Лучше просто файл открывать в текстовом режиме, Python сам разберется что делать с переносами строки.